# Angular material mat grid list not expanded in height

Tags: angular-material, material-design

How to make the mat-grid-list to min-height according to screen

Just I use rowHeight="270px" 
that's right in specific screen but in other screens not working

I tried to make mat-grid-list and mat-grid-tile with height:100% but also not working